# How to do complex filter with for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to filter out observations where in a household if one or both of the spouses has an occupation with this code, then they are included. Otherwise, they are not.

The data has a household serial number to identify the spouses and SOCP for the occupation code

```
structure(list(CBSERIAL = structure(c(2021010001020, 2021010001150, 
2021010003516, 2021010006105, 2021010017230, 2021010017378, 2021010017567, 
2021010021917, 2021010025048, 2021010029253, 2021010031916, 2021010032410, 
2021010033026, 2021010034250, 2021010035095, 2021010039495, 2021010046196, 
2021010048020, 2021010049161, 2021010050046), label = "Original Census Bureau household serial number"
    
US2021A_SEX = structure(c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1"), labels = c(Male = "1", Female = "2"), label = "Sex",
    
US2021A_SOCP = structure(c("373011", 
    "BBBBBB", "493023", "37201X", "493031", "493023", "BBBBBB", 
    "373011", "513099", "499071", "BBBBBB", "BBBBBB", "472061", 
    "472061", "37201X", "BBBBBB", "BBBBBB", "472070", "472070", 
    "BBBBBB"),row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is how I constructed my code.

```
# The following part is filtering the data so that it does not include single-person household
vec <- 0 
pos <- 1

for (i in unique(dat2$CBSERIAL)){
  if (nrow(dat2[dat2$CBSERIAL== i,]) != 1){
    vec[pos] <- i
    pos <- pos + 1
  }
}

dat3 <- dat2[dat2$CBSERIAL %in% vec,]

# The following part is where I have trouble
vec2 <- 0 
pos2 <- 1

for (i in dat3$US2021A_SEX){
  if (dat3$US2021A_SEX == "1" && dat3$US2021A_SOCP %in% (132011:130282)){
    vec2[pos2] <- i
    pos2 <- pos2 + 1
  }
}
```

I tried using a for loop for this, but every time it gives me the error `'Warning: 'length(x) = 352518 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'`

Update: I have updated the code to only include key variables for the function.

Comment: The loop control variable `i in dat3$US2021A_SEX` is not used in the loop. Note that it does not take consecutive numbers, its values are the values of column `US2021A_SEX`. So, the first half of the condition should be `i == "1"`.

Comment: Also, **the end of the posted data set is missing**, your code is not reproducible.

Comment: Post the output of `dput(head(dat2[c("CBSERIAL", "US2021A_SEX", "US2021A_SOCP")], 20))`, please, so that we can try to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the problem correctly, there is no need for `for` loops at all, the code below is vectorized.

```r
# keep only rows with repeated CBSERIAL, so that households with two 
# members are in dat3
i <- with(dat2, duplicated(CBSERIAL) | duplicated(CBSERIAL, fromLast = TRUE))
dat3 <- dat2[i, ]

# now check which households have at least one SOCP 
# in the wanted vector
wanted_socp <- 132011:130282
i <- with(dat3, ave(US2021A_SOCP, CBSERIAL, FUN = \(x) any(x %in% wanted_socp)))
dat3[as.logical(i), ]
#>       CBSERIAL US2021A_SEX US2021A_SOCP
#> 5  2.02101e+12           1       493023
#> 6  2.02101e+12           2       130432
#> 7  2.02101e+12           1       37201X
#> 8  2.02101e+12           2       130706
#> 11 2.02101e+12           1       493023
#> 12 2.02101e+12           2       131581
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

This data set is made up from the data posted in the question.

```r
dat2 <-
  structure(list(
    CBSERIAL = structure(c(2021010001020, 2021010001020, 2021010001150, 2021010001151, 
                           2021010003516, 2021010003516, 2021010006105, 2021010006105, 
                           2021010017230, 2021010017230, 2021010017378, 2021010017378), 
                         label = "Original Census Bureau household serial number"), 
    US2021A_SEX = structure(c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
                              "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2"), 
                            labels = c(Male = "1", Female = "2"), 
                            label = "Sex", var_desc = "", 
                            class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "character")), 
    US2021A_SOCP = c("373011", "373011", "BBBBBB", "131146", 
                     "493023", "130432", "37201X", "130706", 
                     "493031", "493031", "493023", "131581")), 
    row.names = c(NA, -12L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi there, I have updated my question including the three variables, hopefully it would help!

Comment: Also I tried the code, it gave the following error `Error in `vec_restore_dispatch()`:
! Can't convert <logical> to <labelled<character>>.
Backtrace:
  1. base::with(...)
 11. vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
 12. vctrs::vec_default_cast(...)
 13. vctrs:::vctr_cast(x, to, x_arg = x_arg, to_arg = to_arg, call = call)
 14. vctrs::vec_restore(x, to)
 15. vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
 17. vctrs:::vec_restore.vctrs_vctr(x = x, to = to)`